# SQL How to use table variable in Openrowset

Tags: sql, sql-server, openrowset

I use `openrowset` to execute `OperatorsCalc` procedure.

How can I send declared parameters:

1. `@operators` (OperatorTableType)
2. `@number` (int)

into procedure that is executed by `openrowset`?

```
DECLARE @operators OperatorTableType
insert into @operators values ('Mr James')
insert into @operators values ('Mr Johnny')

DECLARE @number int = 3

SELECT *
INTO #MyTempTableForOperators
FROM
    OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=apollo;Trusted_Connection=yes;',
               'SET FMTONLY OFF; 
                SET NOCOUNT ON; 
                EXEC servername.dbname.dbo.OperatorsCalc @number @operators') -- I want to sent parameters @operators and @number in here

select * from #MyTempTableForOperators
```

Comment: Which dbms product  is this for? (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL.)

Comment: microsoft sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [linked server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx), but it may fail if there is nested insert into temp.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (...)

INSERT INTO #temp(...)
EXECUTE [servername].[dbname].[dbo].[OperatorsCalc] @number @operators;
```

Read also [How to Share Data between Stored Procedures by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html).
 There is good chapter about OPENQUERY.

Comment: it worked, thank you also for those links, they are sooooo usefull